# mysqli insert query doesn't seem working with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

http://pastebin.com/VUHbRAuW

I am using ajax, the query did sent but this php page have error, it return nothing, I suspect it was the sql query part.

```
    if($user = $db->query("INSERT INTO post_items(content,date,category_id) VALUES ('$content', '$date', '$category_id'")){

}
```

Comment: Shoot me I am not that Mysqli expert, but can you get output from an `INSERT`? Also you are setting the variables in the `if` and `while`, not comparing with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return something from PHP to your AJAX call you need to use `json_encode` i.e.

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
```